# Running rosjava Node

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the pure java based rosjava not the JNI.  To install rosjava I did:

hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ rosjava_core

then

rosmake rosjava

I tried running an example rosjava Node by typing:

rosrun  rosjava_bootstrap run.py rosjava ParameterServerTestNode

based on the info that

rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py < pkg > < node_class >  [args ... ]

I get:

Buildfile: /home/tori/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/dependencies.xml

get-dependencies:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
Executing command: ['java', '-classpath', u'/home/tori/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/target/org.ros.rosjava-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.test_ros-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.roscpp-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc/target/org.ros.rosjava.apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3.jar:/home/tori/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/target/org.ros.rosjava.rosjava_bootstrap-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.std_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.rosgraph_msgs-0.0.0.jar:/home/tori/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/apache_commons_util/target/org.ros.rosjava.ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/org.ros.rosjava.guava/r07/org.ros.rosjava.guava-r07.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/dnsjava/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava/2.1.1/org.ros.rosjava.dnsjava-2.1.1.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec/1.3.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/1.1.1/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/tori/.m2/repository/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.4.Final/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar', 'org.ros.RosRun', 'ParameterServerTestNode']
Loading node class: ParameterServerTestNode
Unable to locate node: ParameterServerTestNode
```

I went through the tutorial here

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build

and used the source from the rosjava_tutorial_pubsub (the rosjava publish subscribe tutorial)

and again was unsure as to how to run, for example, Listener.class.

Any help as to how to run a rosjava Node would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11249/running-rosjava-node/) by [vbare](https://answers.ros.org/users/1096/vbare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following should run Listener from the pubsub tutorial:

rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener

You need to use the full class name.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0